# in Google Fusion Tables, how do I make a PUT request with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-fusion-tables, put

Looking at [Google Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/style/update), it says that Fusion Tables styles can be updated via PUT requests.

Is it possible to make such a PUT request with Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

There's the `Net::HTTP` library:

```
require 'net/http'
google_api = Net::HTTP.new 'www.googleapis.com'
google_api.get '/fusiontables/v1/tables'
```

This is a simple homemade solution. Maybe you'll have some use for a more extensive framework to access the google api. A quick search on 'google api ruby gem' uncovered [this gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client).

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: In this example, what would I put in the 'www.youraddress.com', '/your_path', and 'data' fields?

Comment: On `.new`, the domain will probably be `'https://www.googleapis.com/'`, then at `.send_request`, `'/your_path'` is the route inside that domain, call it `"/fusiontables/v1/tables/#{tableId}/styles/#{styleId}"` like documented [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/).

Comment: Hm, I checked the Net::HTTP documentation link you posted. I tried a simple 'GET' request, but I keep getting the error: "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (SocketError)". Here is the code on Pastebin (I excluded the tableId and styleId for obvious reasons): http://pastebin.com/AAyn7Ts1

Comment: Found out why. The domain name must be `'www.googleapis.com'`. Edited the answer.

Comment: Alright, I've modded my code to reflect that (http://pastebin.com/Np4nvAQv). I also ran the code with 'net/http' and 'net/https/, and the line 'puts get_req.body' gives me this JSON object showing a 403 error (http://pastebin.com/nbNz2i3D). I wonder why it does that. In the meantime, I'll check out the 'google api ruby gem' documentation some more.

Comment: The 403 error has to do with the google api, but you getting it means the request is 'successful'.

Comment: Indeed. Though I wonder why I'm getting that 403 error. If I type in `https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/#{tableId}/styles?key=#{key}` (with the correct tableId and API key), then I do get the JSON object I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm voting this up because even though my problem isn't solved yet, it at least has pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP POST to do INSERT or UPDATE. Check the [Google online information](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference). There is also a [Ruby library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/#Fusion_Tables_API)

Comment: Hmm, I may be wrong, but I don't see anything on updating a style that way? I'm quite new to this. Do you know if there are examples of updating Fusion Table styles with this sort of HTTP request?

Comment: just follow the link I provided, it shows you how to do CRUD operations in your tables